# Creating EF6 DbContext in multiple tasks C# dotnet 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an EF6 DbContext that i use to load my objects from my database, works great!

But i have a use case where i have lots of child objects that i need to load from the database and then execute some SQL against the database.  In order to get this to run as fast as possible, i have managed to do this using Tasks, but to get round that problem i have had to create a new DbContext for each Task else EF6 throws an exception that multiple queries cannot be executed at the same time.

I have also created my own 'MyProvider' class that i can call to load my context using `_myProvider.Get<NAME_OF_SERVICE>()`.  I have 2 DbContext classes, `NormalContext` i have set as `AddScoped` in DI and only have one of them.  The second `ReadOnlyContext` i use `AddTransient` so that in each builder, a new one is created and i can avoid the error above.

Obviously because i am using Dependency Injection to load each new DbContext i am not disposing of the object (maybe i should, thus the question), but i am seeing some crazy memory usage, my application is running at around 2GB!

So here is a basic code sample, in my code i do using interfaces for DI, but for the sake of this example, i have just created basic classes.  So I would start with calling a method on my web Api, as you can see i have created a basic `HttpGet` method.

```
// used for places where i want to execute multiple queries at the same time
public class ReadOnlyContext : DbContext
{
    public HashSet<ParentObject> ParentObjects { get; set; }
    public HashSet<ChildObject> ChildObjects { get; set; }
}

// used normally by my services
public class NormalContext : ReadOnlyContext
{

}

// example builder that will load an object from the db and execute something against it
public class ChildBuilder()
{
    private MyContext _context;

    public async Task DoStuffAsync()
    {
        var obj = await _context.ChildObjects.FindAsync(1);
        
        // now execute some sql against the database, using the ReadOnlyContext
        // as the queries could happen at the same time
        using (var dr = _context.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
             // do something with data
        }
    }

    public ChildBuilder(ReadOnlyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}

// basic service to load data from db and then spawn multiple tasks to load other data
public class MyService()
{
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private MyContext _context;

    public Task DoStuffAsync()
    {
        // this is using my normal context, which i have one per request (AddScoped)
        var obj = _context.ParentObjects.FindAsync(1);
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        // for the example, i have wrote 10, this could be 1, it could be 50!
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var builder = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ChildBuilder>();
            tasks.Add(builder.DoStuffAsync());
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }

    public MyService(MyProvider myProvider, NormalContext context)
    {
        _myProvider = myProvider;
        _context = context;
    }
}

// HttpController for my web Api
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private MyService _myService;

    // so this would be the method on my api i would call
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync()
    {
        var result = await _myService.DoStuffAsync();

        return OkResult(result);
    }

    public MyController(MyService myService) 
    {
        _myService = myService;
    }
}

// custom provider so i can reference this in business layer
public class MyProvider()
{
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public T Get<T>() where T : class
    {
        var service = (T)_serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(T));
        return service;
    }

    public MyProvider(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
}

// startup.cs
public class Startup
{
    ... basic Startup for web api
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // add services something like this
        services.AddScoped<MyService>();
        services.AddScoped<NormalContext>();
        services.AddScoped<MyProvider>();

        services.AddTransient<ChildBuilder>();
        services.AddTransient<ReadOnlyContext>();
    }
}
```

If you need any more information, please ask.  Driving me up the wall

Comment: In `// do something with data` are you creating any references to objects that might not be promptly disposed?

Comment: I am first obtaining some data and then building an SQL query but loading a raw data reader.  I am using the `.ExecuteCommand' method of the 'DbContext' to do this, but could use a separate SQlDataReader for that bit if needed, but the loading of the object i need to use a DbContext

Comment: Rather than creating multiple instance of you DbContext,  have you consider load the possible data into HashSet<T> or Dictionary? Even though memory consumption will still big, but the speed will greatly increases tho with O(n)

Comment: I could load the objects into some sort of dictionary i suppose and then create a separate SqlReader in each builder to execute my custom SQL...... Yes the objects could be quite big, but we are talking around an average of 50 main objects along with all the child properties and lists of those objects etc.  But if the performance is greater better then it maybe a good pay off.  But this would mean that the objects would need to be obtained in a sync manner one after another and only the execution of SQL done in an async matter